# Restricted access to an artifact in the Maven Repository

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a central Maven repository which is shared by more than one Projects within the Company LAN. Now, I need to have an artifact which is licensed for a single Project, to be placed in the shared repository.

Is it possible set authorized access to that artifact, the credential can ideally be in the pom file of the desired project.

Any better solution is more than welcome.

Comment: This question is specific the Maven repository manager that you are using. All are able to restrict access to artifacts, which would then force you to specify credentials in your Maven settings file (not the POM) http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Servers

Comment: So, that restriction can not be set for some specific artifacts only?

Comment: Yes the restriction can be set for specific artifacts, but how that is accomplished depends on which repository manager you plan on using: Nexus, Artifactory, Archiva. You haven't stated which one you're using....

Answer (score 0):

Maven doesn't handle access rights in repositories, since it's just a client fetching data from a server. If you're using a repository manager, read its documentation. If you're just hosting files behind an Apache HTTPD server, then configure HTTPD.

Alternatively, you could move that file in a separate repository, and configure just one project's POM to use it. This doesn't fix the fact that the repository will continue to be public, so other projects/teams could get to it if they really want to.